# Truncate table with sqlkorma

Tags: sql, clojure, korma, sqlkorma

I just can't get the query to simply truncate a table to work with korma:

```
(korma.core/defentity readings)
(korma.core/exec-raw ["TRUNCATE TABLE ?" [:name readings]])
```

and I get:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "TRUNCATE TABLE ?[*]"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
TRUNCATE TABLE ? [42001-191]
```

Comment: Generally, you can not use bind variable in the position of table name.

Comment: and something like  (k/exec-raw (str "TRUNCATE TABLE " (:name readings)) ) would work here? I really wouldn't want to add another library for this one simple query.

Comment: I think it will work. Just try it yourself. As `truncate` is a DDL, I think will not be invoked very frequently, using dynamic SQL won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments suggests, bind parameter substitution is only for values in DML, not for schema in DML or DDL. It's a semantic distinction, not syntactic.

The

```
(k/exec-raw (str ...))
```

form should work, using the vector form even with an empty parameter vec may not.